# Why is my create-react-app command producing web pack error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I can’t seem to start a new react project with the create-react-app command. I’ve tried installing and reinstalling node several times

Comment: Can you at least show the error message.We can't do any diagnosis without input.

Comment: Please read [how to ask qustions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)